# Place pagebreaks in vim

Tags: vim, text-editors

How would I place pagebreaks in vim (*equivalent to match printing specifications to a white xerox paper of 8.5 x 11 in size*)?

This is so that I don't have to manually adjust the lines to match how it's printed via vim command `:TOhtml`

This is because after line 106, 107 begins at a new page so pagebreak must be automatically placed after every ~106 lines, so to speak.

Since pagebreaks is a word-document function, as far as text-editors go it's by line numbers. So I just need a way to have vim be designed to look like a standard xerox paper and perhaps by default.

- Is it possible to add pagebreaks to vim by default via `_vimrc` file or any other method
- What would be the pagebreak indicator? Is it possible to have it be displayed in any fashion?

---

*Reference:*

- according to *chutz* from [tips.at.gg3.net](https://tips.at.gg3.net/2007/01/23/page-breaks-when-printing-from-vim/), he explains that `"Inserting page breaks when printing in VIM is trivial..."` and in my case it shouldn't be.

Comment: html doesn't have page-breaks as such (specific browsers *may* do something predictable, there are css classes which exploit this).

Comment: html alone may not have pagebreaks, but when vim :TOhtml's it out to a .html file it then should have the proper spacing for the lines intended to be printed on a new sheet rather than being part of the previous one and this avoids it from being cut-off.

Comment: Looking at the script, it does nothing special for line-spacing.  Perhaps you need a different tool.

Comment: @ThomasDickey i've improved the question by adding the specific line from where the pagebreak should be. This is by the 106th line, so line-107 begins at a new page. This is ofcourse, if we're talking about a 2-page file.